# add page transition instead of link transition using jquery blivesta animsition

Tags: jquery, html, css, animsition

I'am using blivesta animsition to add a page transition. But the thing is that I have a link transition at the moment, can anyone help me to create a page transition instead of a link transition. I can't figure it out how.

```
<div
class="animsition"
data-animsition-in-class="fade-in-up"
data-animsition-in-duration="1000"
data-animsition-out-class="fade-out-up"
data-animsition-out-duration="800"
>
<a href="menu.html">Volgende</a>
</div>
```

http://codepen.io/melissabos18/pen/eJJdZm?editors=101

Comment: Please add a [minimal, complete and verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) example to your question, so it's easier for others to identify and solve your issue. For example, you could provide an example using [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/).

Comment: http://codepen.io/melissabos18/pen/eJJdZm?editors=101

Comment: Hey, your pen contains errors in the JavaScript panel.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add a class `animsition-link` to the link.

**CodePen example:** http://codepen.io/grrtbrtr/pen/addmyB

**HTML**:

```
<div class="container animsition" data-animsition-in-class="fade-in-up" data-animsition-in-duration="1000" data-animsition-out-class="fade-out-up" data-animsition-out-duration="800">
  <div class="test">
    <a href="#" class="animsition-link">volgende</a>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: But am i using blivesta animsition now? I think something is wrong in the html because i have a transition but it is a link transition and i want a page transition

Comment: Does the Fiddle I provided (http://codepen.io/grrtbrtr/pen/addmyB) act like you want it?

Comment: http://git.blivesta.com/animsition/fade-up/ i would like to have a page transition like this. But the problem is that the transition is on the link and not on the page

Comment: Hey, please see http://codepen.io/grrtbrtr/pen/addmyB, it mimics the behaviour you want. When clicking the link, the `.container` element moves up.

Comment: ok thanx, is there also an option get fade the other "#" page in?

Comment: Thanx, it's done..... simple copy paste the code to menu.html

Comment: Add `class="animsition" data-animsition-in-class="fade-in-up" data-animsition-in-duration="1000"` to the container element on the other page and initiate animsition there as well...